# Google App Engine returning an HTTP response code of 0

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

[image: screenshot of logs]

As above, my app engine logs are showing requests appearing to be cut off and returning a status code of 0 with no bytes of data. There is no error displayed in the log and no 500's are visible. There are plenty of the same requests passing normally and returning 200s but fairly regularly a 0 will appear.

The pattern seems to be a few HTTP 0s getting returned (the same request is repeated in the logs) and then a 200 is returned. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what this could be?

Thanks,
Richard

--
More technical stuff. 
`instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 2
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: 1s
  max_pending_latency: 2s
  max_concurrent_requests: 3`

Comment: Click on the left caret to see the details, find in there the requested path, find in your code the handler for the path and see if it's not accidentally replying with a 0 code. I do see `0B` sizes on my app as well for small files despite them being served correctly, I guess it could be a size computational artifact.

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks for your response. I don't think it's accidentally returning a 0 as the same request is repeated a few times then goes through with a 200. I'll update the question to provide more details

Comment: Please *do* click on those left-pointing triangles as @DanCornilescu says, and show the resulting details, not just the summary like you're showing -- that's just not enough info to help us help you.

Comment: On an unrelated note (not connected to correctness but to performance and costs), **don't** specify both options meant to reduce latency on traffic spikes (`min_idle_instances`, `max_pending_latency`) *and* ones meant to reduce your cost (`max_idle_instances`, `min_pending_latency`) -- having both kinds of options more or less ensures that the autoscaler will behave suboptimally and surprise you (negatively:-). I'm striving to get this key bit of info into the official docs, but, it's taking a while, so, for now, just please take my word for it!-).

Comment: I've seen this too, even in the logs that I streamed into bigquery